# Issue with Jquery Cookie/Timer

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies, timer

Im building an exam simulator which counts down from 10 minutes, when it hits 00:00 the exam questions are hidden and a div is shown saying "Your our of time" but if i click refresh on the browser it goes back to 10:00 but what i want it to do is show the out of time div again! Iv played around with my jquery below but i cant see where im going wrong, the timer is stored in a cookie so if the user presses f5 at any given time within the exam the cookie carries on counting down from when the user pressed f5! so my question is this can someone help me modify the below JQuery to display the out of time div if the time is 00:00 and remain showing even if the user has refreshed the browser.

```
   $(function () {
                $('.clock').each(function () {
                    var clock = $(this),
                    theTime = $.cookie('time'),
                    seconds = "00", minutes = 10;
                    if (theTime && theTime != "0:00") {
                        theTime = theTime.split(":")
                        minutes = theTime[0]
                        seconds = theTime[1]
                    }
                    $('.min', clock).text(minutes)
                    $('.sec', clock).text(seconds)
                    var timer = setInterval(function () {
                        var m = $('.min', clock), minutes = +m.text(),
                            s = $('.sec', clock), seconds = -1 + +s.text()
                        if (seconds < 0) {
                            seconds = 59
                            minutes--
                        } else if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
                            clock.html('Timer Complete.');
                            clearInterval(timer);
                            $.cookie('time', '', { expires: -1 })
                            $('#feedbackform').hide();
                            $('#MainContent_DivOutOfTime').toggle();
                            return;
                        }
                        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds
                        m.text(minutes)
                        s.text(seconds)
                        $.cookie('time', minutes + ":" + seconds, { expires: -1 })
                    },
                1000);
                });
            });
```

Iv tried removing the following from the code

```
 if (seconds < 0) {
   seconds = 59
   minutes--
 } else
```

That way it would check the time and then display the div but with no avail! i also removed the clearInterval... any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you getting the correct data from `$.cookie("time")`?

Comment: Just so you realize, all anyone has to do to defeat your cookie-based system is to manually clear the cookie, run another browser, go to another computer, create a different user on their computer, etc...  Even when you get this to work, it will take seconds to bypass.

Comment: @jfriend00 what would be the best way to stop any of what you have mentioned from happening?

Comment: Preventing cheating on a web-based test is a large topic, but you would have to start by keeping track of time and access on the server because the user cannot mess with the state there like they can with cookies.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the information ill have a google and see what i can come up with

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this line clear the cookie? Try removing it.

```
$.cookie('time', '', { expires: -1 })
```

Comment: Found out why its resetting because of this line when it first comes in to the function seconds = "00", minutes = 10;